# Wrong animation when insert or delete items in UICollectionView

Tags: swift, animation, collectionview

I want insert item in the collectionView, if collectionView offset equal 0 no problems observed, But if I scroll my collection and after that try insert new item, my collection starts acting weird.

All items are compressed, then decompressed at the beginning of the collection

(All inserting into 0 index)

`DeleteItem` calls the same effect

I assume that the collection includes an animation to insert a item, and at the same time it scrolls to this new item, two animations overlap each other. (That's what I found out, read other answers)

Why the animation breaks when removed - I, unfortunately, do not know, I hope you help me)

My code for insert and delete items:

insert:

```
// Calls in collectionView custom class
func insertTag(_ tag: String) {
        tags.insert(tag, at: 0)
        performBatchUpdates {
            self.insertItems(at: [.init(item: 0, section: 0)])
        }
        
    }
```

delete:

```
// Calls on collectionView custom class
func removeTag(_ tag: String) {
        let deletedIndex = tags.firstIndex(of: tag)
        guard let deletedIndex = deletedIndex else { return }
        tags.remove(at: deletedIndex)
        deleteItems(at: [.init(item: deletedIndex, section: 0)])
    }
```

Insert item (when contentOffset > 0)
[image: insert gif]

Delete item (when contentOffset > 0)
[image: delete gif]

**I really hope that you will help me figure it out, I'm sure that the solution should be on the surface (I think so)**